# What controls the output format from the command line date /t

Tags: windows-10, date

I have two logons on the same machine. If I type the command `date /t` one of them shows:-

```
18/03/2024
```

and the other one shows:-

```
Mon 18/03/2024
```

I would like to have them both the same.

I imagined that this would be controlled by region date and time settings, but on the second logon (which shows the day of the week preceding the date, the setting show the following. So I guess this isn't what controls it after all.

[image: Customize Format - Date tab]

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having gone to the lengths of taking a screen grab and writing this up I noticed that on one logon, my Short date format was:-

```
dd/MM/yyyy
```

and on the other it was:-

```
d/MM/yyyy
```

Note, the single letter 'd' instead of two of them.

Initially I was, "nah" that can't be it, that surely just controls whether you have a leading zero or not? Anyway, I thought, I'll just try in, just in case.

And pow! There it is. That's the difference. So thought I had better write it up, since it is certainly not obvious to me!

To summarise, in region date settings:-

```
Short date: dd/MM/yyyy
```

`date /t` shows:

```
18/03/2024
```

or

```
Short date: d/MM/yyyy
```

`date /t` shows:

```
Mon 18/03/2024
```